# What should I do if an else statement is not executing after if/elif statements didn't meet the condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, visual-studio-code

I have an issue with my codes. I received an output meant for an if statement whenever the `rice_ingredients = input("How many ingredients: ") is > 8` instead of the output of else statement which should be "Too much ingredients, unprofessional!"

```
def Chef() -> int:
    rice_ingredients = input("How many ingredients: ")
    for ingredients in rice_ingredients:
        if ingredients <= str(6):
            print("Professional")
        elif ingredients == str(7) or str(8):
            print("Well, can still be considered professional")
        else:
            print("Too much ingredients, unprofessional!")
        exit()
```

Comment: `elif ingredients == str(7) or str(8):` == `elif (ingredients == str(7)) or (str(8)):`. You need to do either `elif ingredients == str(7) or ingredients == str(8):` or `elif ingredients in [str(7), str(8)]:`

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
elif ingredients == str(7) or str(8):
```

is different from:

```
elif ingredients == str(7) or ingredients == str(8):
```

and this:

```
elif ingredients == (str(7) or str(8)):
```

---

The second form is probably the logic you want to implement, which could also be written as:

```
elif any(ingredients == str(x) for x in (7, 8)):
```

or:

```
elif ingredients in {str(7), str(8)}:
```

---

## EDIT

Also, perhaps you want to check the code as a whole:

- `Chef()` does not follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) naming conventions and does not return a `int` (contrarily to your annotation).
- `rice_ingredients` contains a string which should contain a single number (based on the question you ask `"How many ingredients: "`), looping through it will cause you to consider each character of the input separately, so that if you type `123`, `ingredients` will be `1`, `2` and `3` at each iteration. Likely, what you want to do is convert `rice_ingredients` to `int`, e.g. `rice_ingredients = input("How many ingredients: ")` to become `rice_ingredients = int(input("How many ingredients: "))`
- now that `rice_ingredients` is a `int` you do not need to compare it against strings
- `exit()` will completely exit the interpreter, if you just want to quit the function use `return` instead. Note that is is not needed to explicitly exit from the function at the end of it -- it will automatically do so
- the logic of the `if`-`elif`-`else` clause can be simplified further

A possible cleaned up code would look like:

```
def chef():
    rice_ingredients = int(input("How many ingredients: "))
    if rice_ingredients <= 6:
        print("Professional")
    elif rice_ingredients <= 8:
        print("Well, can still be considered professional")
    else:
        print("Too much ingredients, unprofessional!")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood your question, but there is a logial error:

```
def Chef() -> int:
    rice_ingredients = input("How many ingredients: ")
    for ingredients in rice_ingredients:
        if ingredients <= str(6):
            print("Professional")
        #elif ingredients == str(7) or str(8): please note
        elif ingredients == str(7) or ingredients == str(8):
            print("Well, can still be considered professional")
        else:
            print("Too much ingredients, unprofessional!")
        exit()
```

Please also note that in this case you should consider a different check eg (`<` and `>`) or a `in`

Answer (score 1):

This can also solve your problem. As essentially you want to compare number, converting to integer is logical.

```
def Chef() -> int:
    rice_ingredients = input("How many ingredients: ")
    for ingredients in rice_ingredients:
        value = int(ingredients)
        if value < 7:
            print("Professional")
        elif value < 9:
            print("Well, can still be considered professional")
        else:
            print("Too much ingredients, unprofessional!")
```